# Why use an else statement when the if statement returns a value?

Tags: c, if-statement

I am wondering, when an if statement within a function returns a value, is it necessary to proceed it with an else statement to return a different value? For example:

```
char to_lower_case(char ch) { 

   if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') 
       return ch - 'A' + 'a'; 
   else 
       return ch; 

}
```

Couldn't the else statement be negated and have the same effect since the if statement will return a value and exit the function when the condition is met?

```
char to_lower_case(char ch) { 
 
    if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') 
        return ch - 'A' + 'a'; 
  
    return ch; 
 
}
```

Comment: `is it necessary to proceed it with an else statement to return a different value` no, it is not necessary, both your examples will work exactly the same and actually will produce exactly the same binary code

Comment: Some linters will complain about the first one and recommend / require to use the second.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine and produce identical results.